# How to force Mathematica to return `NumericQ` as True when aplied to some variable in Mathematica?

Tags: data-types

I want to get a general formula for an expression, so instead of numbers like 5 or Pi I want to insert variables into an expression. But the functions involved check `NumericQ` on the arguments and do not evaluate for a symbolic variable. Can I force Mathematica to return `NumericQ` as True for a set of variables?

I tried:

- `NumericQ[a]=True` - no error but does not work
- The same but with `Unprotect[NumericQ]` - no effect
- `$Assumptions=a \[Element] Reals` - no effect

What else should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) or [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)

```
a /: NumericQ[a] = True;
```

Then

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := x^2

f[a]

(* a^2 *)
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for variables with lower index

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What do you mean by "variables with lower index"?

Comment: Such as $a_1$, $b_2$.

Comment: As a workaround `Format[a1] = Subscript[a, 1]; a1 /: NumericQ[a1] = True; f[a1]`

Comment: [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/26598): 3. Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code. While it can be done, it causes a lot of confusion and is harder to use than just `sym[j]` or whatever your symbol might be. The reason is that subscripted symbols are not plain symbols, so you can’t assign values (strictly speaking, `DownValues`) to them directly. See also general discussion about "indexed variables".